# Is it possible to run docker on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

Is it possible to have nested virtualization in AWS with the EC2 in order to use Docker or Kubernetes or should I rather use the ECS (elastic container service) for Docker or EKS ( elastic kubernetes service) for Kubernetes?

-The reason I am asking this question is first if is possible to run docker or kubernetes on EC2 and in case I can why there are such services as EKS and ECS?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You CAN run docker on an EC2 instance, but it depending on your use-case it might not be considered a good idea. 
I've got Jenkins hosted in a Docker container on EC2 which in turn probably will be using some ECS slaves. So yeah, definitely doable.

Comment: People do this all the time, and there are prominent tools like kops for deploying Kubernetes on an EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you guys, much clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run a container on a VM. This is described [in Docker's introductory documentation](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container). ECS and EKS both have the option to run on EC2 instances. The reason to use ECS and EKS is to outsource the management of the orchestration tooling. Many people have and continue to manage the orchestration themselves for either control or cost savings, while many others look for opportunities to outsource these pieces.